# Pythonic way to create an idempotent method

Tags: python

Let's have a class with a `start` method. It can be called many times, but the actual start code should be executed only once. Subsequent calls should do nothing. (a fancy word for it is *idempotence*)

Sounds easy:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self._started = False

    def start(self):
        if self._started:
            return
        # start code
        print('start')
        self._started = True
```

The problem is that the test must be repeated in all derived methods:

```
class C2(C):
    def start(self):
        if self._started: # don't forget!
            return
        # additional code
        super().start()
        # additional code
```

---

My solution #1:

I split the `start` into two functions:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self._started = False

    def start(self):
        # DO NOT OVERRIDE THIS ONE
        if self._started:
            return
        self._start()
        self._started = True

    def _start(self):
        # start code
        print('start!')

class C2(C):
    def _start(self):
        # additional code
        super()._start()
        # additional code
```

---

The second attempt replaces the `start` method with a noop func after first call (precisely it creates a noop function in the instance that shadows the method in the class, but the effect is the same).

```
class C:
    def start(self):
        # start code
        print('start!')
        self.start = lambda: None

class C2(C):
    def start(self):
        # additional code
        super().start()
        # additional code
```

---

I'm not happy with my solutions, do you know a better one?

UPDATE: What I dislike:

#1: to modify `start` you must not touch `start`, but modify other function

#2: it is self-modyfing code

Comment: What properties exactly would a "better" solution have? Asked like this your question is too broad to give a specific answer.

Comment: Your #1 is the famous [NVI pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-virtual_interface_pattern).  What’s wrong with it, exactly?

Comment: I appended what I dislike.

Comment: @DavisHerring Could not find much info about Python and NVI pattern, but if my question is a special case of related Template Pattern (with just 1 step to override instead of usual several steps) I would drop my objections against  #1 and accept it.

Comment: This question is about trying to find a new and fancy way to do something we do the boring way.

Comment: Btw, "idempotence" means that a function always returns the same output for a set of inputs, not that it only runs once.

Comment: @DovRine I understand it this way: _"Modules should be idempotent, that is, running a module multiple times in a sequence should have the same effect as running it just once."_ (source: Ansible docs) We have functions/methods, not modules, of course.

Comment: @VPfB: Here's another example: __add__ is idempotent for the int class, too, but it doesn't just run once. It always returns the same output for the same inputs. Basically, idempotent functions/methods do not have side effects like modifying global state. Modules should be idempotent b/c no one is expecting that importing a module will mutate their application's state.

Comment: @DovRine: Idempotence strictly refers to functions *f* such that for all *x*, *f(f(x))=f(x)*.  These functions **project** their entire domain into a subset on which their restriction is the identity.  In imperative programming, it is applied to **actions** by considering the unary function that maps the system state to the subsequent state (disregarding such things as the instruction pointer).  `C.start` certainly qualifies here (for each `C` separately).

Comment: @VPfB: Python can’t *enforce* NVI like C++ or Java (any more than it can enforce class member access control), but that doesn’t mean you can’t or shouldn’t use it.

Comment: @DavisHerring: Well said. I agree that the use of C.start makes this class idempotent. I was simply pointing out that idempotence is not quite as OP described it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea that what is overridden in a derived class might not be an element of the public interface but some internal function that implements *part* of that interface is known as the [non-virtual interface pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-virtual_interface_pattern).  (When there are several such parts for one public method, it is more commonly known as “template method”.)  The terminology comes from C++ (originally from Simula), where such a pattern can be enforced since only `virtual` functions *can* be overridden.  Python relies on convention for (many) such things, of course, but the pattern is no less appropriate for it.

Your solution #1 is therefore unsurprising and reasonable; #2, on the other hand, relies on a little-used feature that doesn’t work with `super` or with manual up-calls like `C.start(self)`.